# Django: Update related object on save?

Tags: django, django-forms

I've "extended" Django's contrib.auth.models "user" like:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'profile')
   date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
   avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_avatar_path, null=True, blank=True)
   friends = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name = 'user_friends', blank=True, null=True)
   bio = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I'd want the user to be able to update email from UserChangeForm, something like this:

**forms.py**

```
class UserUpdateForm(UserChangeForm):
   email = forms.EmailField()
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super(UserUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.fields.pop('username')
      self.fields['email'].initial = self.instance.user.email

   class Meta:
      exclude = ('friends', 'username', 'password1', 'password2')
      model = UserProfile
```

Except that one doesn't save the email.

I thought of trying to access request.post data from post_save signal so I could set user's new email there, but couldn't get that one working.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the form's `save` method as well:

```
class UserUpdateForm(UserChangeForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        exclude = ('friends', 'username', 'password1', 'password2')
        model = UserProfile

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields.pop('username')
        self.fields['email'].initial = self.instance.user.email

    def save(self, commit=True):
        self.instance.user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if commit:
            self.instance.user.save()
        super(UserUpdateForm, self).save(commit)
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir. Your efforts shall be rewarded!